# Claim and Proof of Claim within Proof of a Theorem

Tags: reference-request, proof-writing, solution-verification

While writing a proof of a theorem for a journal can we use the Claim environment within the Proof environment?

Suppose I want to break a step in the proof as a Claim and proof the claim, but the claim cannot be posed separately since it is very specific to a step of the proof a theorem. In that case, can we write the Claim and the proof within the proof itself?

If someone shows me an example where there are such instances it will be great.

Please let me know if I am allowed to post this question here? Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: @User8976 your question looks fine to me, and it is properly tagged (even though `solution-verification` is perhaps pushing it). @JaapScherphuis your two comments packed in an answer would get my upvote. That's exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: I turned my comments into an answer.

Comment: If this is truly the clearest way (that you can find) to present the argument, go for it! (But also consider the alternatives provided in the answer.) If the referees or the editor don’t agree they will probably ask you to change it, but it is very unlikely that your paper will be rejected outright because of something like this.

Answer (score 2):

It is normal to state and prove lemmas which are then used to prove a main theorem. It is common to state the main theorem first, then state some further definitions and state/prove several lemmas about the things that were just defined, essentially setting up all the machinery needed for a proof, and then finally give a proof of the main theorem (where you use the lemmas).

If the claim/lemma really is too specific to build up to before starting the main proof, you could instead merely state it at the point you use it in the main proof, and then restate and prove the lemma afterwards. That way you keep the main proof more concise and readable.